# Does the meter in the Canon AE-1 work well?

Tags: canon, slr

I have an old Canon AE-1. I want to start using it. I noticed there is a light meter in it, but how accurate is it? I don't want to waste a roll of film trying to figure it out.

Thanks!
Estevan Montoya

Answer (score 1):

Use the sunny-16 rule to test how accurate the meter is.

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunny_16_rule):
**"On a sunny day set aperture to f/16 and shutter speed to the reciprocal of the ISO film speed for a subject in direct sunlight."**

For example if you are using ISO 100 film, set the AE-1 to shutter priority mode and shutter speed 1/100 sec (or 1/125 if that setting is not available) focus somewhere outside on a sunny afternoon then your light meter should recommend setting a f-stop of f16 or something closer.  If it does then you can be pretty sure about its accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the camera's recommendations with what you get from a source you trust, such as a light meter or another camera.  Note that if you use another camera that's more modern and has multi-point metering, you should set it to center weighting to emulate what your AE-1 is doing.  Film is more forgiving than most digital sensors, so exposure will be fine as long as it's close.  (This assumes nothing in the camera has been damaged and a fresh battery.)

This document has some useful technical information about the AE-1, including a description of its metering system:  http://www.baytan.org/prak/pdf/CanonAE1add.pdf

Comment: Negative film is forgiving, yes - slide film will be LESS tolerant than most digital sensors. However, the light meters in AE-1 era SLRs were definitely designed with slide film in mind, so if they are in good shape, they will be quite accurate.